# Display title list of all post of current post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type called `press`.

What I want to achieve is generate a list of the titles (with it's corresponding link to it) of all `press` custom post types.

I tried with this code with no luck, any ideas?

```
    <?php function all_posts_custom_posts( $query ) {
            $post_type =  $query->query_vars['post_type'];

            if ( 'press' == $post_type ){
                    $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = -1;
                    return;
            }
    } 
    add_action('pre_get_posts', 'all_posts_custom_posts',1); ?>
```

And also highlight the current post from the list by adding a `class` to it.

Comment: Off the top of my head, do `echo $post_type;` on line 3 to see what it spits out. Also try to flip the comparison on line 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue sometime ago. The following code example will display how I resolved my issue.

```
<?php
$type = 'products';
$args=array(
  'post_type' => $type,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1

$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
    <?php
  endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>
```